# rugarch package. egarch estimation

Tags: r

I'm trying to estimate an EGARCH model, via the rugarch package in R, for a returns series. Here are the codes:

```
espec2 <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list("eGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)), 
                     mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0), include.mean = TRUE), 
                     distribution.model = "std")
EGARCHSTDfit <- ugarchfit(spec2, rendimenti, solver = "solnp", 
                      fit.control = list(stationarity = 1))
```

Then I type

```
EGARCHSTDfit
```

to see the model, but I get this result

```
 Conditional Variance Dynamics  
-----------------------------------
GARCH Model : sGARCH(1,1)
Mean Model  : ARFIMA(1,0,1)
Distribution    : std
```

and all the features are the same as I specified a "sGARCH" model.
 So I don't get an EGARCH. Did I make any mistake? Why do I not obtain an EGARCH? Any suggestions? Thank you very much

Comment: This appears due to a typo, and missing variable assignment. Try this instead: `spec2 <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "eGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)), mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0), include.mean = TRUE), distribution.model = "std")`

Comment: That's working! Thank you Clark